# SocketTimeoutException:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out caused by JSchException:com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail

Tags: java, sockets, jsch

I have a socket service, which is listening for when a request arrives, from a client also in java, when this request arrives, the service connects via ssh to a server to retrieve information. The ssh connection is via JSch, when you have a correct username and password, everything works fine, but when you have a wrong password, it causes an exception
(`com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail`), when the session.connect() is executed, something happens that my connection between the client and the socket service that is listening, causes a (SocketTimeoutException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out)

Show the next exception

```
SocketTimeoutException:
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:181)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:326)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:392)
at Gopher.sendCmd(Gopher.java:149)
at Gopher.main(Gopher.java:110)
```

and then shows the other exception

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
at com.networkInterface.SshWorker5.doConnect3(SshWorker5.java:235)
at com.simpleSw.ossgw.connectionDaemon.command.CfiCmdV3.execute(CfiCmdV3.java:2663)
at com.simpleSw.ossgw.connectionDaemon.Connection.run(Connection.java:71)
at com.simpleSw.ossgw.connectionDaemon.DaemonThread$ConnectionThread.run(DaemonThread.java:90)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

the process is as follows

1 - the request is sent via a shell program
2 - the shell sends the request to the client in java (Gopher.java)
3 - the client performs a process to select which socket (server) to send the request to (4 sockets (servers) listening)(Thread.java)
4 - The server receives the request and tries to connect via ssh to the server indicated by the request.
5 - The ssh connection is through JSch, when the `session.connect()` command is executed, the `SocketTimeoutException` appears and the process ends in the shell that started the request, I don't know what happens internally in the session.connect command
6 - After a few seconds the 2nd exception appears (`com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail`) but the client can no longer receive anything because it gave the time out exception

This is the code that send the request (client)

```
            try {
SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(getHostName(), getPort());

                NetIntSocket = new Socket();
    
                NetIntSocket.connect(sockaddr, 5000);
    
                NetIntSocket.setSoTimeout(getTolerance());
    
                socketOut = new PrintWriter(NetIntSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                socketIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(NetIntSocket.getInputStream()));
    
                socketOut.println(getCommand());
                String line;
                boolean isUDC = isHLRUDC(getCommand());
                while ((line = socketIn.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (isUDC) {
                        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("EPDPIND   EPDPADD|        NO");
                        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
                        if (!matcher.find())
                            System.out.println(line);
                    }else {
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                }
    
                return true;
```

this is the ssh connection code

```
    public boolean doConnect3(String sshusr, String sship, String sshpwd, String command, PrintWriter out) throws JSchException, IOException {
String result="";
String result2="";

        try {
            JSch jSch = new JSch();
            session = jSch.getSession(sshusr, sship, port);
            session.setPassword(sshpwd);
            
            Properties config = new Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.setTimeout(timeout);
            out.println("Antes session.conect timeout ["+timeout+"]");
            session.connect();     ------------------------------------> here causes the exception
            out.println("Despues session.conect timeout ["+timeout+"]");
            
            channel = session.openChannel("shell");
            channel.connect();
    
            expect = new ExpectBuilder()
                    .withOutput(channel.getOutputStream())
                    .withInputs(channel.getInputStream(), channel.getExtInputStream())
                    //.withEchoOutput(System.out)
                    //.withEchoInput(System.err)
                    .build();       

//           out.println("Entro al try doConnect3.expect \["+channel.isConnected()+"\]");
return channel.isConnected();
} catch (JSchException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
out.println("JSchException out \[ "+e+" \]");
System.out.println("JSchException System.out \[ "+e+" \]");
Logger.getLogger(SshWorker5.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "JSchException:", e.getMessage());
out.println("JSchException getMessage() \[ "+e.getMessage()+" \]");
out.println("JSchException getCause() \[ "+e.getCause()+" \]");
out.println("JSchException getStackTrace() \[ "+e.getStackTrace().toString()+" \]");
return false;
} catch (Exception e) {
//            out.println("Exception \[ "+e.getMessage()+" \]");
e.printStackTrace();
Logger.getLogger(SshWorker5.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "SshConnectionException:", e);
}
//        out.println("Entro al try doConnect3.catch \["+channel.isConnected()+"\]");
return false;
}
```

I forgot to tell you that when this exception occurs, it no longer prints anything with the lines of out.println that are in the code. and I can't retrieve the `e.getMessage, e.getCause, e.getStackTrace`.

This is a part of code that call th ssh connection

```
                            if (sshSlave5.doConnect3(apgdata\[1\], apgdata\[0\], apgdata\[2\], MmlNe\[0\], out)) {
out.println("");
out.println("\<\<\<\<\< " + MmlNe\[1\] + " \>\>\>\>\>");
out.println("");
out.println("\<" + MmlNe\[0\]);
out.flush();
pod = sshSlave5.executeCommand(MmlNe\[0\], out);
//                              out.println("Saliendo de sshSlave5.executeCommand \["+pod+"\]");
sshSlave5.disconnect();;
out.println(pod);
doPMlog(MmlNe\[1\], MmlNe\[0\], initTime, "YES", Integer.toString(ActiveQueries), "Executed");
} else {
pod = ServantData.getACCESSERRMSG();
pod = pod + "\\nOSS connectionStatus \[" + qryRS + "\]";
out.println(pod);
out.flush();
doPMlog(MmlNe\[1\], MmlNe\[0\], initTime, "NOT", Integer.toString(ActiveQueries), "ACCESSERRMSG");
}
```

In this part it returns for the else but no longer prints the out.println

Does anyone know if the JSch has a bug, what could cause this?